# how can i capture the output of an echoed string

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
 <?php
//Page info
$PageTitle = "Johnson electrician";
$search_for =
array('Electrical Serviceh' => array('electrical', 'audio', 'electrician', 'security'), 'Plumbing Servicey' => array('heating', 'gas'));
     foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){
         foreach ($term as $findme)
         {
             if (strpos($PageTitle,$findme) !== false)
             {
             echo $name;
             }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

where it says "echo $name;" i would like it the $name to become a variable, i can use anywhere later on, but just echoing $name just gives me a field when used outside the script, not the output of the script:

I have tried the following but doesnt work with multiple outputs:

worked in my last step with single values: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vowaKO, but now you can enter multiple values you get all results when you echo it directly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/38sRBX . So i tried doing the same with your new code so it outputs to a variable i can use buts fails: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9b4q3t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the values of $name in another variable for future reference. For example, in another array:

```
<?php
//Page info
$PageTitle = "Johnson electrician";
$nameArray = array();
$search_for = array('Electrical Serviceh' => array('electrical', 'audio', 'electrician', 'security'), 'Plumbing Servicey' => array('heating', 'gas'));
 foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){         
     foreach ($term as $findme)
     {
         if (strpos($PageTitle,$findme) !== false)
         {
         $nameArray[] = $name;
         echo $name;
         }
    }
}
// to check the total array
print_r($nameArray);

// iterate over the array values
foreach ($nameArray as $name)
 {
     echo "<br/>".$name;
}

// to print selective values. note: index starts from 0
echo "<br/>".$nameArray[0];
echo "<br/>".$nameArray[1]; // and so on...
?>
```

**Updated code as per discussion in comment section (to echo $name only):**

```
<?php
//Page info
$PageTitle = "Johnson electrician";
$nameArray = array();
$search_for = array('Electrical Serviceh' => array('electrical', 'audio', 'electrician', 'security'), 'Plumbing Servicey' => array('heating', 'gas'));
 foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){

     foreach ($term as $findme)
     {
         if (strpos($PageTitle,$findme) !== false)
         {
         $nameArray[] = $name;
         echo $name;
         }
    }
}
echo '<br><br>';
echo $name = implode($nameArray, ', ');
?>
```

Comment: was ob_get commands was thing to use foreach again, thats amazing thank you.

Comment: Still doesnt put the vale into its own variable, although offers further solutions. i will need to manipulate the outputed value further eg. $var = str_replace('  ', ' ', $var);

Comment: Actually $name is not its own variable. It is a name given to the iterator associative index.

Comment: so how would one put the output of the script "the value of $name" into a variable. As the above options are further prints and echos of the output.

Comment: you missed this line: $nameArray[] = $name; This is where we are assigning the value again to another variable.

Comment: $nameArray[] = $name; is there, not sure i understand?

Comment: Exactly, that is where we are putting output value of $name to a variable i.e. $nameArray. $nameArray is a separate variable we introduced to store the values of $name. If it is still unclear, please let me know your query in more details.

Comment: Okay but this doesnt allow me to echo the value directly ei. echo $name

Comment: thats printing all the name fields not the "matched" results eg. electrician so Electrical Servicesh would print only unless the word "gas" was found too.

Comment: This is how i want it to work, but this only deals with one word match so had to alter the code to search each word. but can not use "$myvar= $name;" any more  http://codepad.viper-7.com/vowaKO

Comment: I think the code I provided suffices. You should use an array.

Comment: The last one outputs the entire string and comments

Comment: on that code it works, thats the old code, but couldnt handle more then one word in $PageTitle so added a loop so it scans each word, "     foreach ($term as $findme)" but now i cant use $myvar=$name;

Comment: I believe your initial question has been answered. If you have another question, please open another thread. If you think, your initial question's answer is good enough, please accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: its the same question, and it only does what it did in the first place echo the value, doesnt capture the value and put it into a variable.

Comment: will accept the answer if no one else answers it later on, for the time you put in to help

Comment: No issues, don't accept it if you think it was not good enough. However I would like to differ from your this statement: "doesnt capture the value and put it into a variable." $nameArray is the variable that is containing the values.

Comment: but cant find a way to crack $nameArray open outside the script so i can play with the values. want to be able to use it outside the script, not echo it.

Comment: ok got somewhere with it, it works but only puts 1 value into the variable "$output". http://codepad.viper-7.com/c8aMBi  it should say "electrical services " "space" "plumbing services" but just print the last value.